# Delete files permanently using batch or vb.net

Tags: vb.net, batch-file, delete-file

We have gotten new computers yay! However we have some mid-sensitive information on the old PC's and I wanted to know how we could delete these files permanently (beyond the capabilities of recovery software). Once that is done we can give the olderones away to staff for there kids.

I program using batch however if there are more effective vb.net methods available then I can program using this language too.

The information on the PC's is nothing overly sensitive but we do keep occasional autocad drawings on them that we'd rather just keep in house (not out house), other then that the pc's are in good condition a little old but a shame to physically destroy when others might be able to use them for homework and so..

Comment: StackOverflow is meant for programming related questions. This question is better suited for [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/). By the way, Chrome has a very handy built-in [spell-checker](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95604).

Comment: Depending on the sensitivity of the data and the eagerness to recover it, sometimes destroying the disk is really the only way to be sure.  Save the rest of each computer, but drop the hard drives into a professional data shredder.  (Or keep them in-house as a stack of spare hard drives, I suppose.)

Comment: @cyborgx37 this is not a spelling form ;)

Comment: @ABANDONDACOUNT Did you mean "forum"? ;)

Comment: yeah like I said its not the end of the world if the information slips out, however its just what we decided in he meeting to be good practice. hens a standard deleting or re-formating is ample but if perminate deletion was much harder the why not?

Comment: @ cyborgex37 english isnt my native tongue lol

Comment: @ABANDONDACOUNT - I would think that a simple reformat would be sufficient for family of employees.

Comment: What about the Windows licenses? How are you going to transfer those?

Comment: never mind i found a downloadable by microsoft alled sdelete

Comment: @ AbqBill we just reinstall Windows xp on the pc as far as my understanding goes the licence is per pc not per user, like any other secondhand pc?

Comment: I have read about a technique used where once you delete sensitive data, you use the cipher command on it. I'm not 100% sure about this, but it might help. I'll try to find the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

There may be more to consider here than just the data.  What about software licensing?  Is Windows installed on those machines?  Are you allowed to give away copies of Windows?  (I'm guessing no.)  Any other software?

A few ideas of what to do with the hard drives may include:

1. Removing the hard drives and having them professionally destroyed.  No chance of data recovery, short of industrial espionage intercepting them from the destruction company or internal to your company.  You *probably* don't need to go this far, but it is safe.
2. Removing the hard drives and keeping them.  Just giving people empty computers where they can install their own drives.
3. Destructively formatting the hard drives.  This performs repeated read/write tests on the drives and pretty effectively over-writes any data.  That way you're not just removing files but also any and all software that you may not be permitted to give away.  It also assures the recipients that the drives have been through pretty rigorous testing and don't have bad sectors.
4. Normal-formatting the hard drives.  Data can possibly still be recovered if the attacker wants it bad enough.  This is *probably* your best course of action given your expressed (implied) risk/reward ratio.
5. The computers are being given to kids?  Rip apart the hard drives and have a craft project day where the kids make wind chimes out of the platters.  It's a lot of work, but hard drive platters make *awesome* wind chimes.  (And if you have any Ferrofluid around, the magnets in the hard drives are very effective for making pretty cool effects with that.)

Comment: David never mind the software licences, such responses render these forum questions to be closed e are not giving away coppies of windows as licenses are subject to th pc they are intalled with, each. but for the sake of avoiding this spin off topic "Im buying new windows for every kid getting the PC to cover that...(not) end of topic. slegehammering pcs works but not if you intend to give them away afterwoulds. as for the attacker yeah school kids want autocad drawings BAD like addics to meth... kids hate wind chimes unless it involves baked beans... forums why do I bother

Comment: +1 I, for one, think this list of options is extremely reasonable. @ABANDONDACOUNT - I think option 5 was a joke (that kids will destroy the computers anyway). Option 4 is pretty reasonable. You can always hand people a blank machine and let them install their own OS (Windows, Linux, etc.)

Comment: @Cyborgx37: 5 was partially a joke, but I've actually done that at a children's technology class and they loved it.  (Depends on the age of the children, I imagine.)  You're right in that 4 is probably the best bet.  It's also standard practice whenever this sort of thing comes up anywhere else.  Sounds to me like the OP already knows what he wants to do, though, so I'm not really sure what the point of the question was.

Comment: 5 is a joke but with some of the responss in forums who knows in that case my appologies (however dont under estimate kids often they know how to handel pc's better then adults and that sadly isnt a joke) other then that lets just quit the os licence issue its copleatly off topic, though the licens it tied to the pc not the usser (we cleard this up with microsoft) option 4 is not reasonable considering it is exactly this which we are trying to overcome, (perminatly deleting as in unrecoverable re installations dont resolve that) other then that no harm intended in my coment

Comment: topic closed, and wont be responed to anymore by poster as aswers are unconstructive.

Comment: @ABANDONDACOUNT - You may also want to consider that not all sensitive information is contained within files. You may have settings in various programs which could be harmful to your organization. For example, passwords stored in your browser, SMTP settings stored in Outlook, registry settings with license keys (for software that you *aren't* giving away). You may be legally or financially liable in some cases, and your company may be put at risk in others. You can't stop someone from turning around and reselling the PC to someone more nefarious.